# If Death was the one who created the Resurrection Stone, how did the 2nd Peverell brother know how to turn it thrice before it works?

Tags: harry-potter

If we assume that it was Death who created the Resurrection Stone, how did the 2nd Peverell brother know how to turn it thrice in his hand before it works?

Comment: Why would we assume that?

Comment: @Valorum we don't know which of the two (Death and Cadmus) created it. Dumbledore says it was most probably Cadmus, but we know he isn't always right.

Comment: [Does personified Death really exist in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54713/does-personified-death-really-exist-in-harry-potter) - Spoiler, no, almost certainly not

Comment: so if we assume Cadmus was given the stone why is it unreasonable to think that he was told how to use it as well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm inclined to agree with Dumbledore here:

> "So it’s true?" asked Harry. "All of it? The Peverell brothers –"
>   "– were the three brothers of the tale," said Dumbledore, nodding. "Oh yes, I think so. **Whether they met Death on a lonely road ... I think it more likely that the Peverell brothers were simply gifted, dangerous wizards who succeeded in creating those powerful objects.** The story of them being Death’s own Hallows seems to me the sort of legend that might have sprung up around such creations."
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*, chapter 35: "King's Cross" (emphasis added)</sub>

So... it's not that Death gave them the objects, but that the Peverell brothers created them themselves. As such, they'd know how they work.